# Datastore emulator message type mismatch

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I tried to start the datastore emulator in my local dev environment (Java 8) and got the following error. Looks to me it happens because of a mismatch of protobuf versions. It would be great if you know of any workaround for this. Thanks.

Cloud SDK Version: 313.
OS: macOS

$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start

```
Executing: /Users/w/Work/google-cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/cloud-datastore-emulator/cloud_datastore_emulator create --project_id=<aaaa> /Users/w/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore

[datastore] Oct 09, 2020 12:28:45 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.CloudDatastore$CreateAction$1 apply

[datastore] INFO: Provided project_id to Cloud Datastore emulator create command, which is no longer necessary.

[datastore] Created new Cloud Datastore project in '/Users/w/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore'.

Executing: /Users/w/Work/google-cloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/cloud-datastore-emulator/cloud_datastore_emulator start --host=localhost --port=8081 --store_on_disk=True --consistency=0.9 --allow_remote_shutdown /Users/w/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore

[datastore] Oct 09, 2020 12:28:45 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.CloudDatastore$FakeDatastoreAction$9 apply

[datastore] INFO: Provided --allow_remote_shutdown to start command which is no longer necessary.

[datastore] Oct 09, 2020 12:28:45 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.LocalDatastoreFileStub <init>

[datastore] INFO: Local Datastore initialized:

[datastore] Type: High Replication

[datastore] Storage: /Users/w/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin

[datastore] Exiting due to exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Extension is for type "proto2.MethodOptions" which does not match message type "google.protobuf.MethodOptions".
```

Comment: as the error message pointed out that in the local_db.bin the config there is a object has a "proto2.MethodOptions" is not follow the type "[google.protobuf.MethodOptions](https://hexdocs.pm/exproto/Google.Protobuf.MethodOptions.html#content)". please double check it . for the [Protocol Buffer Basics: Java](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial)you can refer for this documentation.  if you still encounter the issue, can you provided the part of the codes here?

Comment: The same error is issued even when the local_db.bin file is not already available. That means the dev app server has not created any data in local_db.bin.

Sorry, I didn't get it. What do you mean by the part of the code? My guess is there is no application code involved at this point.

Comment: for my understanding, it seems the dependency looking for 'google.protobuf' but found 'proto2'..ever try to import proto2 as google.protobuf?  Can you provide your dependency file ?